# Unable to start proftpd server debian 8

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

I'm trying to configure an FTP server on debian 8. I'm using the basic conf file of `proftpd`, found [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/configs/basic.conf)

Now when I try to start the server I get this error:

```
[....]
 Starting proftpd (via systemctl): proftpd.serviceJob for proftpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status proftpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

logs:

```
juin 04 10:47:52 client1 proftpd[2325]: Starting ftp server: proftpd2015-06-04 10:47:52,978 client1 proftpd[2331]: fatal: unknown configuration directive 'DisplayF
juin 04 10:47:52 client1 proftpd[2325]: failed!
juin 04 10:47:52 client1 systemd[1]: proftpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
juin 04 10:47:52 client1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts ProFTPD daemon.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) proftpd.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- L'unité (unit) proftpd.service a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
juin 04 10:47:53 client1 systemd[1]: Unit proftpd.service entered failed state.
```

Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 3):

May be you have error in your `proftpd` config file. You have to perform configuration check. The easiest way to do informative syntax check as is stated [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) is to run:

```
proftpd -td10
```

or you can run (less noise):

```
proftpd -td5
```

For sample config in your question, the result is:

```
2015-06-04 12:05:43,290 debian proftpd[22458]: using PCRE 8.35 2014-04-04
2015-06-04 12:05:43,291 debian proftpd[22458]: using TCP receive buffer size of 87380 bytes
2015-06-04 12:05:43,291 debian proftpd[22458]: using TCP send buffer size of 16384 bytes
2015-06-04 12:05:43,292 debian proftpd[22458]: mod_memcache/0.1: using libmemcached-1.0.18
2015-06-04 12:05:43,293 debian proftpd[22458]: <Directory />: adding section for resolved path '/'
2015-06-04 12:05:43,293 debian proftpd[22458]: fatal: unknown configuration directive 'DisplayFirstChdir' on line 53 of '/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf'
```

So may be you have to comment line:

```
DisplayFirstChdir       .message
```

Comment: The command `proftpd -td5` helped me to clearly see where the error ist, though I have another error.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_DisplayChdir.html the `DisplayFirstChdir` directive has been obsoleted by `DisplayChdir` with the supplementary `true` parameter.

So instead of:

```
DisplayFirstChdir .message
```

You now need:

```
DisplayChdir .message true
```

If you want the message displayed every time someone enters that directory, omit the `true`.

---

<sup>How did I find this out? I went to the [website for ProFTPd](http://www.proftpd.org/) and looked in the documentation, finding [Directives By Name](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/by-name.html). It became apparent that `DisplayFirstChdir` was not a valid verb, so I looked at the nearest equivalent by name.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem removing the main FTP configuration file `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` and then restarting the service

```
sudo service proftpd restart
```